# Quadratic Equation with Matrix [Prove Invertible]

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

The problem is:

"The  $2\times 2$ matrix **A** satisfies $A^2-4A-7I=0,$ where **I** is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. Prove that **A** is invertible."

The hint given is:

"We are trying to a matrix that is the inverse of **A**."

I completed the square and was proceeding to take the square root of both sides when I realized the identity matrix has multiple square roots.

Comment: You're not following the hint. If there exists a matrix $B$ such that $AB=I_2$, then $A$ is invertible and $A^{-1}=B$. You're given that $A^2-4A=7I_2$. Finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that $$ AB=BA=I$$
where $B=7^{-1}(A-4I)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here your question is "Prove that **$A$ is invertible**". For this you have to show that $det (A) \neq 0$.

Now since $A$ is a $2× 2$ matrix, satisfies the polynomial equation $x^{2} − 4x - 7 = 0$ (as $A^2-4A-7I=0$ is given) which contains non-zero constant term $(-7)$, so $det (A) =-7 \neq 0$. Therefore $A$ is invertible. [Q.E.D]

** Now if you have to find $A^{-1}$, then you can proceed as follows

$ A^{2}-4 A-7 I=0 $ .......(1)

Since A has an inverse, so multiplying both side of equation (1) by $A^{-1}$ we have

$A^{-1} ( A^{2}-4 A-7 I ) = A^{-1}. 0 \implies A^{-1} . A^{2} -4 A^{-1}. A - 7 A^{-1} . I=0 \implies A - 4 I - 7 A^{-1}=0 \implies A^{-1} = \frac{1}{7} (A - 4 I) $